# jQuery: Colorbox + Form - Accessing posted data + some miscellaneous questions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox, jquery-forms-plugin

My goal is to submit a form in a [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) modal via ajax (that part is complete), and then take one of the submitted values (called 'percentage') and update a value in a table.

I've got my code below (sans form).  You can see that a link is opened with the Div containing my form (#Form_PlayerSave) and that form is ajaxified through the awesome [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).  The form is submitting correctly, now I just want to update the 'percentage' part of a table.

There is php included in the script because I need 25 forms per page (one for each row of the table), so each $x just counts off the different forms.

So, what do I do?  What I have below returns undefined, and I've tried quite a few varied solutions.

I also have noticed that when the link in the table to open the Colorbox modal is clicked again, it displays the page that the form would normally submit to had it not gone all ajaxy.  Any ideas on how to fix this so user can update the value to their little heart's content?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   function prepform(){



       $('#Form_PlayerSave<?= $x ?>').ajaxForm({
           // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response
           target: '#customPlanDiv<?= $x; ?>',

           // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response
           // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content
           success: function() {
                 $.fn.colorbox({html:"Custom Plan Saved", open:true});
                 var x = $('#Form_PlayerSave<?= $x ?> :percentage').fieldValue();
                 $('#custom_plan_text<?= $x ?>').val(x[0]);
           }

       });
   }

   $(".customPlan<?= $x; ?>").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#customPlanDiv<?= $x; ?>"}, prepform);

});
```

**I really appreciate everyone's help!  Thanks * 10!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

               function prepform(){

                    $('#Form_PlayerSave<?= $x ?>').ajaxForm({
                               // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response

                               beforeSubmit:  CPshowRequest<?= $x ?>,
                               // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response
                               // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content
                               success: CPshowResponse<?= $x ?>,
                               resetForm: true

                   });

               }

               $(".customPlan<?= $x; ?>").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#customPlanDiv<?= $x; ?>"}, prepform);

         });

            // pre-submit callback
            function CPshowRequest<?= $x ?>(formData, jqForm) {
                var x = $('#percentage<?= $x ?>').fieldValue();
                $('#custom_plan_text<?= $x ?>').html(x[0]);
                return true;
            }
            function CPshowResponse<?= $x ?>(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
                $.fn.colorbox({html:"Custom Plan Saved", open:true});
            }
```

Why this works beats me, but it does. :)

Also, for future onlookers, to make sure the div doesn't get replaced onsubmit simply make sure target doesn't point to your original form's div (dumb dumb dumb on my part).